# DatePickerDialog ICS - Get the date to display in the title

Tags: android, dialog, datepicker, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, datepickerdialog

I've just recently updated my personal phone to Android 4.0.4. Doing so, I've noticed that the `DatePickerDialog` which I display in my application is no longer showing the long date format in the title bar like it would in previous versions :

[image]

Instead it simply says : 'Set date'.

So, is there a quick way to make it so that this particular `DatePickerDialog` always display the long date in the title bar ? Or is this a version limitation which I'll have to overcome by creating my own custom `Dialog`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, is there a quick way to make it so that this particular DatePickerDialog always display the long date in the title bar ?

The former update-the-title logic is completely removed from [the current `DatePickerDialog` source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/DatePickerDialog.java). You should be able to extend `DatePickerDialog` and override `onDateChanged()` (and the six-parameter constructor) to restore this functionality, at least in theory -- I have never tried this.

FWIW, [here is a link to an older version of `DatePickerDialog`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/9066cfe9886ac131c34d59ed0e2d287b0e3c0087/core/java/android/app/DatePickerDialog.java) that had the update-the-title logic.